# Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. how to fix it?

Tags: android, flutter

i am create demo of flutter RewardedAds but i fetching some error like:

**[ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
Ad failed to load : 3**

how to solve it.

My Code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:admobdemo/RewardedAdsExample.dart'; import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   MobileAds.instance.initialize();   runApp(MyApp()); }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   // This widget is the root of your application.   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Admob ad example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RewardAdsExample(),
    );   } }
```

**RewardedAdsExample.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'adMob/admob_controller.dart';

class RewardAdsExample extends StatelessWidget {
  AdmobHelper admobHelper = new AdmobHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reward Ads Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  admobHelper.createRewardAd();
                },
                child: Text("Load Reward Ads")),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  admobHelper.showRewardAd();
                },
                child: Text("Show Reward ads"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**adhelper.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdHelper {
  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform');
    }
  }

  static String get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  static String get rewardedAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }
}
```

**admob_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:admobdemo/adMob/adhelper.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class AdmobHelper {
  late RewardedAd _rewardedAd;

  static initialization() {
    if (MobileAds.instance == null) {
      MobileAds.instance.initialize();
    }
  }

  void createRewardAd() {
    RewardedAd.load(
        adUnitId: AdHelper.rewardedAdUnitId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
            print('$ad loaded.');
            // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
            this._rewardedAd = ad;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            print('RewardedAd failed to load: $error');
          },
        ));
  }

  void showRewardAd() {
    _rewardedAd.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem rewardItem) {
      print("Adds Reward is ${rewardItem.amount}");
    });

    _rewardedAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdImpression: (RewardedAd ad) => print('$ad impression occurred.'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: got any updates on it?

Comment: @lazydevpro i can not get any update for this.